# Jquery remote completion, li's are not selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a text input with text completion using a remote host.

I've been trying to use the example in the following URL: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/

this is the javascript code from the example:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                q: $input.val()
            }
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});
});
```

so first of all I changed dataType from jsonp to json which makes the ajax call
return a proper json object and the unordered list is filled properly.

the problem that I encounter is that once I see the text completion (the li elements), I can't select any of the elements.

I tried browsing this example on my Galaxy Note 2 and I encountered the same problem, the elements are not selectable.

any ideas how to resolve the issue?
thanks

## update

as to @Omar comment i changed the following line:

```
html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
```

to

```
html += "<li><a href='#'>" + val + "</a></li>";
```

now i can click on an item but it doesn't do anything. it supposed to close the list and add to the text field the selected item.

Comment: what do you mean by selectable? clickable?

Comment: yeap :) i'm supposed to be able to click on one of the elements and none of them is clickable.

Comment: Because you're using read-only listview. For clickable list items, `a` anchor should be placed inside `li`, e.g. `<li><a href='#'>" + Val + "</a></li>`.

Comment: thanks @Omar, updated main post. items are clickable but aren't doing anything.

Comment: By default, they won't do anything. You have to run your own code once any item is clicked.

Comment: @Omar i don't know how to get the text element from the autocomplete component in order to fill it with the proper text.

Comment: If you go with my solution below, you don't need to add anchor to list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate an event to generated list items and then update input with the value.

```
$("#autocomplete").on("click", "li", function () {
    /* text of clicked element */
    var value = $(this).text();

    /* update value of input */
    $("#autocomplete-input").val(value);

    /* optional - remove autocomplete result(s) */
    $(this).parent().empty();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gwudrd18/)**